# Which lib (libmyshlib.so, libmyshlib.so.1, libmyshlib.so.1.0) is best to add into my project?

Tags: c++, qt, shared-libraries

I'm trying to make shared library in QtCreator on Linux. I've got:

- `libmyshlib.so`
- `libmyshlib.so.1`
- `libmyshlib.so.1.0`

So which file should I load/add into project?

Comment: They are probably all the same (thru symlinks). Read Drepper's [How to write shared libraries](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) paper. You'll use `-lmyshlib` for your link command.

Answer (score 0):

.so and .so.1 file is for symbolic linkage

.so.1.0 is for pointing indirectly

usually we use the file with  pure .so file and we don’t include the other files in including library for development.

Comment: Actually, `libmyshlib.so` and `libmyshlib.so.1` usually are symbolic links, and indirectly point to `libmyshlib.so.1.0`